# Unable to download server on client side. Can not connect VS Code with wsl

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I can't connect VScode with wsl (Ubuntu 22.04). It gave me these errors.

--2024-01-19 17:54:54--  https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/server-linux-x64/stable
[2024-01-19 12:24:54.736] Resolving update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)... 13.107.246.58, 13.107.213.58, 2620:1ec:bdf::58, ...
[2024-01-19 12:24:54.736] Connecting to update.code.visualstudio.com (update.code.visualstudio.com)|13.107.246.58|:443... connected.
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] Location: https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] --2024-01-19 17:54:54--  https://vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com/dbazure/download/stable/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] Resolving vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com (vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com)... 152.199.39.108, 2606:2800:247:1cb7:261b:1f9c:2074:3c
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] Connecting to vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com (vscode.download.prss.microsoft.com)|152.199.39.108|:443... connected.
[2024-01-19 12:24:55.047] Unable to establish SSL connection.
ERROR: Failed to download https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681/server-linux-x64/stable to /home/supuna97/.vscode-server/bin/8b3775030ed1a69b13e4f4c628c612102e30a681-1705667094.tar.gz

I want to connect VScode with wsl. I need a nice answer to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure your internet connection's time zone and system's time zone are matching